# Solving the congruence for powers

Tags: number-theory

What is the abstract method to solving the follow congruence below? I am completely stuck on how to solve this.

$a^{n} \equiv b$ mod$(m)$, where $a, b, n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

For example: $x^{101} \equiv 7$ mod (12).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fermat's little theorem is a general strategy for these kinds of things. We have $x \cdot x^{100} = x \cdot (x^{4})^{25} \equiv 7 \pmod{12}$. Notice $\phi(12) = 4$ (here $\phi$ represents the Euler totient function), and so we have $(x^4)^{25} \equiv 1 \pmod{12}$. Hence, we have $x \equiv 7 \pmod{12}$. You can read more about it here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

Comment: Why am I allowed to say $\phi$(12) = 4? Why is x $\equiv$ 7 mod 12 from the step when you said $(x^{4})^{25}$? Sorry, I'm really confused with the step after that. I'm also asking as for the general steps on how to solve the abstract case.

Comment: No worries. $\phi(n)$ counts the number of integers less than n which are relatively prime to $n$. For 12, we have that these are $3, 5, 7, 11$, and so $\phi(12) =4$. Since $(x^4)^{25}$ is 1, multiplying this to $x$ mod 12 is the same as multiplying 1.

Comment: In the general case, you want to simplify your powers to be as small as possible when working. The wikipedia article talks a little bit about how you can rework things using Fermat's Little Theorem. I would have to think more about the abstract case, but Fermat's Little Theorem is pretty much how I would always start these problems.

Comment: So I need to have $\phi$(12)*a + k = 101 and then after that use Fermat's Little theorem to get x alone right?

Another question is since 12 is't prime, how come $(x^{4})^{25}) \equiv 1 (mod 12)

Comment: Good question. This leads into a generalization of Fermat's little theorem called Euler's theorem. You can see it here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem